# node_save() null tid column

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to create a node programatically like so,

```
$newNode = (object) NULL;
$newNode->type = 'job';
$newNode->title = $data['JobTitle'];
$newNode->uid = $user->uid;
$newNode->created = strtotime("now");
$newNode->changed = strtotime("now");
$newNode->status = 1;
$newNode->comment = 0;
$newNode->promote = 0;
$newNode->moderate = 0;
$newNode->sticky = 0;
$newNode->tid = 0;

$newNode->summary['und'][0]['value'] = $data['JobSummary'];
$newNode->body['und'][0]['value'] = $data['JobDescription'];
$newNode->field_employment_type['und'] = strtolower($data['JobType']);
$newNode->field_job_reference['und'][0]['value'] = $data['JobReference'];
$newNode->field_salary['und'][0]['value'] = "";
$newNode->field_salary_from['und'][0]['value'] = $data['SalaryFrom'];
$newNode->field_salary_to['und'][0]['value'] = $data['SalaryTo'];
$newNode->field_salary_override['und'][0]['value'] = $data['Salary'];
$newNode->field_application_email['und'][0]['value'] = $data['ApplicationEmail'];
$newNode->field_job_category['und'][2] = 2;
$newNode->field_job_category['und'][4] = 4;

//die(print_r($newNode));
// save node
node_save($newNode);
```

Here I have potentially 4 taxonomies to pick from (their id indicated in brackets) Creative (2), Technical (3), Marketing (4), Client Services (6).

On `node_save` I am getting the following error,

> 500 Internal Server Error : An error occurred (23000):
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tid'
>   cannot be null

How do I overcome this this I would have thought setting the `field_job_category` to the id of the taxonomy would be enough?

Comment: Try to create your node using [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity), take a look at  the second example in this article  [Create a Node in Code](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/create-a-node-in-code)  .  **Note From the article** `fewer lines of code, better clarity, and less trouble from language/translation issues`

Answer (score 1):

If you have one tid by node use:

```
$tid = 0;    
$newNode->taxonomy[0]->tid = $tid;
```

if the node can have more than one term use:

```
$tids = [0, 3, 4, 5];
$i = 0;
foreach ($tids as $tid) {
  $newNode->taxonomy[$i]->tid = $tid;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: If my taxonomy is a custom field called job category would I do, `$newNode->field_job_category[$i] = $tid`

Comment: Yes, if you use a multilangual site use this: `$newNode->field_job_category[$newNode->language][$i]['tid'] = $tid;`